# Usar Identity en proyecto asp.net mvc 5 ya creado

Tags: asp.net, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, identity

Actualmente poseo una app web creada en con ASP.NET MVC 5, la cual esta trabajando con una base de datos ya creada. En este punto me gustaría usar `Identity` para poder crear formularios y manejo de usuario a la pagina, el problema es que no se como realizar la configuración desde inicio para una pagina que ya esta creada sin perder todo el trabajo realizado. Si alguien que haya tenido mi mismo problema me pudiera ayudar, le agradecería mucho.

Comment: Este tutorial quizás te ayude: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final logre resolver el problema, todo es cuestión de escribir el `connectionString` de forma correcta en el `Web.config`.

Por defecto viene de la siguiente forma:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication1-20180725105224.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication1-20180725105224;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

En este caso yo lo sustituí por la forma que tiene el `connectionString` que crea EntityFramework Code First, que es muy parecida a esta:

```
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="data source=TuServidorBD;initial catalog=TuBD;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;encrypt=False;trustservercertificate=False;applicationintent=ReadWrite;multisubnetfailover=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Espero sea de ayuda